# Navigation menu disappears in landscape mode if the user clicks the toggle button in portrait mode in my responsive website

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I created a collapsed menu for a responsive website.

When the site is viewed in a browser whose width is less than 960px, the navigation menu items are stacked and hidden. The user needs to click a toggle button to reveal the navigation items. When the browser width is more than 960px, the navigation menu items are displayed in a line.

My problem happens when the user browse the site on a iPad. If the user first open the site on a iPad in portrait mode (width < 960px) and clicks toggle button to reveal the navigation menu and then clicks the toggle button again to hide the navigation menu. Now if the user rotates his iPad to landscape mode (width > 960px), the navigation menu disappears.

But if the user opens the site on a iPad in portrait mode and then rotates it to landscape mode without clicking the toggle button, the navigation menu is available in landscape mode.

**The following is the javascript code I wrote to hide and reveal the navigation menu:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Get the handlers
    var collapseBtn = $('#nav-collapse');
    var mainNav = $('#main-nav');

    // Navigation menus only collapse when they are not floated
    var isFloated = mainNav.children('li').css('float');
    if (isFloated != 'left') {
        // Add toggle button click event listener
        collapseBtn.on('click', function() {
            mainNav.slideToggle();
        });

    }

});
```

**The following is the html code:**

```
<nav class="col-lg-12">
    <a class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">Menu</a>
    <ul class="clearfix" id="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://apple.com.au">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**The following is the css code:**

```
/* toggle button */
#nav-collapse {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#CDD1F4;
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
    color:#ffffff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#nav-collapse:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* main navigation */
ul#main-nav {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
    display:none;
}
ul#main-nav li {
    z-index:9;
}
ul#main-nav  li a {
    display:block;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
}
ul#main-nav  li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#CDD1F4;
    color:#ffffff;
}

/* first level navigation */


/* second level navigation */
ul#main-nav > li > ul {
    display:none;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:2%;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {

    /* toggle button */
    #nav-collapse {
        display:none;
    }

    /* main navigation */
    ul#main-nav, ul#main-nav ul, ul#main-nav ul li {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    ul#main-nav {
        line-height:1;
        list-style:none;
        display:block;
        overflow:visible;
    }
    ul#main-nav li a {
        font-size:13px;
        color:#6D87C3;
        display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family: 'pt sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
    ul#main-nav  li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#6D87C3;
}

    /* first level navigation */
    ul#main-nav > li {
        float:left;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        position:relative;
    }
    ul#main-nav > li > a {
        line-height:10px;
        padding:0px 12px 0px 7px;
        border-right:1px solid #6D87C3;
        border-bottom:none;
    }
    ul#main-nav > li:hover > ul {
        display:block;
    }

    /* second level navigation */
    ul#main-nav > li > ul {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
    }
    ul#main-nav > li > ul > li {
        background-image:url('../img/trans3.png');
    }
    ul#main-nav > li > ul > li > a {
        width:220px;
        padding:15px 10px;
    }
    ul#main-nav > li > ul > li > a:hover {
        color:#ffffff;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is jQuery's `.slideToggle()` method dynamically adds a `style: none` to the element you are toggling, straight into the tag. So, it takes precedence over your media query rules set in your CSS. To overcome this issue, in your media query targeting devices with screen widths above 960px, add an `!important` to the `display` rule for the `#main-nav`.

```
ul#main-nav {
    line-height:1;
    list-style:none;
    display:block !important;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Another thing I noticed was your determining factor for adding a listener to the click event on your navigation toggle. If it's dependent on the `#main-nav`'s float attribute, then when the page is first loaded in landscape then switched to portrait the slide toggle will not work, because no listener has been attached to the `#nav-collapse` element on load. Something like the following approach should take care of that though:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Get the handlers
    var collapseBtn = $('#nav-collapse');

    collapseBtn.on('click', function () {
        //if the device is desktop prevent toggle of nav
        if (screen.width >= 960) 
            return;
        mainNav.slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try :)

Comment: Thanks, it works. And also thank you for pointing out other bugs in my code.